# print the code of a function in a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, printing

I want to print the code of a function in a DLL.

I loaded the dll, I have the name of the desired function, what's next?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have source code for that dll? What do you mean with _print the code of a function_?

Answer (score 3):

Realistically, next is getting the code. What you have in the DLL is *object* code -- binary code in the form ready for the processor to execute, not ready to be printed.

You *can* disassemble what's in the DLL. If you're comfortable working with assembly language, that may be useful, but it's definitely *not* the original source code (nor probably anything very close to it either). If you want to disassemble it, loading it in your program isn't (usually) a very good starting point. Try opening a VS command line and using `dumpbin /disasm yourfile.dll`. Be prepared for a *lot* of output unless the DLL in question is *really* tiny.

Comment: And if you're not comfortable working with assembly language, you can use IDAPro or a similar decompiler to get C code that does the same thing as the original... but it won't be the original code -- no comments, no variable names, for and while loops may be changed to do loops, etc.

Comment: @Ben: IDA Pro is still a disassembler, not a decompiler. It's a very good disassembler (if you're going to do things like this much, it's well worth the investment) but you still need to be comfortable at the assembly language level to use it.

Comment: Ok, the decompiler is named Hex-Rays.  It's from the same company.

Comment: @Ben: yes, it's from the same company, but separate -- and in all honesty, if you're not comfortable at (or at least close to) the assembly level, it probably won't do a lot of good either. As decompilers go, it's not bad, but it still renders quite a bit pretty close to assembly code with C syntax, not much like what you'd typically write in C.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option to retrieve hints about the actual implemented functionality of said function inside the DLL is to reverse engineer whatever the binary representation of assembly happens to be. What this means is that you pretty much have to use a disassembler(IDA Pro, or debugger, e.g. OllyDbg) to translate the opcodes to actual assembly mnemonics and then just work your way through it and try to understand the details of how it functions.

Note, that since it is compiled from C/C++ there is lots and lots of data lost in the process due to optimization and the nature of the process; the resulting assembly can(and probably will) seem cryptic and senseless, but it still does it's job the exact same way as the programmer programmed it in higher level language. It won't be easy. It will take time. You will need luck and nerves. But it IS doable. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. A DLL is compiled binary code; you can't get the source just by downloading it and knowing the name of the function.

If this was a .NET assembly, you might be able to get the source using reflection. However, you mentioned C++, so this is doubtful.

Comment: The copmiled binary data is inside the DLL. You can see it by opening the DLL in a hex viewer. There's nothing useful there, though.

Comment: Nothing useful isn't quite accurate, the full machine code is there (and with a disassembler, can usually be read). Doing much of anything with that, though, might get interesting.

Comment: @peachykeen: That's what I meant by "nothing useful there". If the OP is trying to print a DLL, the full machine code probably isn't going to be too helpful. :)

Answer (score -1):

Check out this http://www.cprogramming.com/challenges/solutions/self_print.html and this [Program that prints its own code?](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/64590) and this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

I am not sure if it will do what you want, but i guess it may help you.

Comment: -1 This explains how to print source code. The poster doesn't have the source code, so this is not an answer. Printing text doesn't help when you have a binary DLL - try it yourself. Open a small DLL file in Notepad and try to print it and see if you get anything useful.

Comment: The poster did not say he does not have the source. I just assumed the source was available.